# problem in addition of listing

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a Table of content, list of figures. Now want to add `listoflisting` (on next page of list of figure).  Table of content and list of figure are proper from content point of view. But `listoflisting` has only title with no content. What command I should add so that all used lists appear in the `listoflisting` automatically? I have read the post (Make a "List of Lists" in addition to "List of figures" and "List of tables" on stackoverflow Latex. But it is not working.
`\usepackage{newfloat}` & `\usepackage{listings}` are also added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\title{Sections}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
This is the first section.
\blindtext
\section{Section main}
This is the main section.

\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\centering
THIS IS A FIGURE
\caption{A long figure caption so we can see how it looks in the LoF.
         Is this really long enough?}
\end{figure}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{lstlisting} [ label = {Listing1}, abovecaptionskip=10pt]
Integer a b c,
int a=5
Int b=4
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tcolorbox}
 \captionof{lstlisting}[Listing]{constants variables}
 \captionsetup{format=plain}

List of list here.
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid your question is hard to answer without code and it is not easy to find a specific post on this site without a link. Please edit your post and provide a complete but minimal document which illustrates your problem, along with links to any relevant posts you've identified. `listings` is for typesetting source code. AFAIK, there is no default command to produce a list of lists of things. In general, this would only add unnecessary clutter, since most documents have 3 such lists at most (contents, figures and tables) and the latter two are often included in the first.

Comment: Please don't add tags arbitrarily. Your question has nothing to do with Overleaf. Assuming you're using it, it's just providing you with an editor and TeX installation.

Comment: Please don't downvote new users' questions before they've had a chance to respond to comments!

Comment: Thanks for providing code. I added the `\end{document}` you forgot. If you could provide a link to the question you reference, that would be very helpful. Just realised you have two `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in the middle. Are these separate files?

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to list? Your example document doesn't contain any source code listings, so a list of them will obviously be empty.

Comment: It is same file. ( I have removed start document from the middle). In section main there are lists, as there are figures in this section.  Within the section main , list appears normally but while i am making index then there is no description of lising. But have proper list of figures in the index. First,table of content->list of figure->want listoflist here(but nothing is there)

Comment: So does your real document have source code listings? And the problem is you want a list of those listings? If so, you should add a sample source code listing to the example so there is something to be listed. By 'index' do you mean the list of figures? Or do you mean the list of figures is included in the table of contents? Your document doesn't have an index, which is a different thing.

Comment: I have added a list in code. List content appears properly. Only problem lies in making list of list. I have list of figure. Now want to have list of list also.

Answer (score 1):

Properly define a new float type.

I also suggest to use `tcolorbox` features to ease input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=lol,
  listname={List of Listings},
  name=Listing,
  placement=tp,
]{listing}

\captionsetup[listing]{
  position=bottom,
}

\renewtcblisting{lstlisting}[1][]{listing only,listing options={#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoflistings

\section{Introduction}
This is the first section.

\section{Section main}
This is the main section.

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

THIS IS A FIGURE
\caption{A long figure caption so we can see how it looks in the LoF.
         Is this really long enough?}

\end{figure}

\begin{listing}[htp]

\begin{lstlisting}
Integer a b c,
int a=5
Int b=4
\end{lstlisting}

\caption{constants variables}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem. Now content,list figure,list of listing appears with proper content. But next two pages are empty just with title of content, list figure . How i can remove these two pages because they are useless.